# Word for "thing not to disclose" in an NDA

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word to describe **"the thing you're not allowed to disclose"** when talking about an NDA? For example, how would I complete the following sentence:

"Non disclosure agreements are required when a party wishes to prevent the other from disclosing information about [...])"

Comment: Typically *confidential|proprietary|sensitive information* and/or *trade secrets*. You used the wrong homonym of *you're*.

Answer (score 1):

Most NDAs I've signed have referred to "sensitive information" (which agrees with one of Dan Bron's suggestions)

I would just say "Non disclosure agreements are required when a party wishes to prevent the other from disclosing sensitive information"

Comment: I would say something like "A non-disclosure agreement *might* be used when a party wishes to prevent a second party from disclosing sensitive information."  It's only "required" if the first party requires it, and then only valid if the second party accepts it as a condition of their transaction.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh I agree with your statement for sure. I only sought to suggest the word I would use within the context that was provided... so perhaps framing it with "I would say" was not entirely accurate.It was not my intention to corroborate the exact definition offered, only to suggest a word to be used in said definition.